# What are the improvements in the different Selenium versions

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, robotframework

I am working on test automation.
Are there any advantages in upgrading `selenium` to different versions?

Answer (score 3):

All the improvements in different Selenium releases can be found in the [selenium - master - py - CHANGES](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/master/py/CHANGES) page:

> Selenium 4.0 Alpha 3
>
> - Fixing stacktrace parser to handle strings as well as objects
> - urllib throws on 404 so let's check the /status endpoint that returns 200
> - Changing default command executor address to the address of TNG Grid
> - Fixing check of type of a returned element in a test for all_of condition
> - Implement logical expected conditions in Python (#7121)
> - Explicitly clear PoolManager by using context manager (#6878)
> - Fix invisibility_of_element expected condition init function (#7484)
> - fix docs build, add chromium and edge to docs
> - flake8 fixes
> - allow --browser-binary and --browser-args to be used with ChromiumEdge
> - Add support for the new MicrosoftEdge (#7459)
> - increase async script timeout from 0 as the w3c spec states to start time checking immediately
> - fix unit test for firefox options, proxy key should be outside of options
> - update to w3c compliant log endpoints
> - Remove 'resolve_ip' option from RemoteConnection (#1729,#2509)
> - Running python unit tests with bazel
> - Pass capabilities rather than options to the proxy object (#6620)
> - Adding full page screenshot feature for Firefox (#7182)
> - Added EventFiringWebElement to the isinstance check in the move_to method.(#6604)
> - Added socksVersion field in proxy class (#6983)
> - also clear w3c actions in ActionChains#reset_actions
> - fix edge webdriver init by deprecating edge_service in favor of service also fix warnings import in edge/webdriver
> - Removes old exception and dead code from py lib.(#7134)
> - Raise error for unsupported method for set_window_rect
>
> Selenium 4.0 Alpha 1
>   * Update driver initialisation to use service and option objects
>   * turn on keep-alive by default for remote connections (#7072)
>   * Fix ConnectionResetError
>   * Add new Cast commands
>   * Suggest download Microsoft Webdriver over HTTPS
>   * Clear PoolManager in ‘remote_connection’ to ensure sockets are closed
>   * remove --disable-gpu option for headless Chrome
>   * Add support for the New Window command (#6873)
>   * Update docstrings in Options classes to allow documentation to highlight Return values
>   * Fix typos in select.py (#6925)
>   * Remove native events handling code
>   * Deleting unused imports, fixing flake8 issues
>   * Remove unused port selection in IE Driver
>   * Enabling tests xpassed in Chrome
>   * Pretty-printing code samples
>   * remove all deprecated methods and args from Python bindings
>   * Fix DeprecationWarning: invalid escape sequence
>   * Don't override browser options with desired capabilities by default in WebKitGTK (#6814)
>   * Add WebKitGTK to API docs (#6815)
>   * Subclass options classes from a common base class (#6522)
>   * Update Sphinx (#6728)
>   * WebDriverWait: update documentation for until and until_not (#6711)
>   * Fix typo in description of WebDriver class (#6724)
>   * add strictFileInteractability to acceptable W3C capabilities
>   * Deprecate Blackberry Driver support
>   * Fixing/tidying docstring.
>
> Selenium 3.141.0
>   * Bump version to a better approximation of ?
>   * Improved Test build targets
>   * fix os path in test for Windows
>   * use 'NUL' for /dev/null on Windows
>   * Update ctor docstrings to explain that a directory passed in is cloned. Fixes #6542
>   * Allow passing of service_args to Safari. Fixes #6459
>   * Remove element equals url
>   * Improved WebExtension support
>
> Selenium 3.14.1
>   * Fix ability to set timeout for urllib3 (#6286)
>   * get_cookie uses w3c endpoint when compliant
>   * Remove body from GET requests (#6250)
>   * Fix actions pause for fraction of a second (#6300)
>   * Fixed input pausing for some actions methods
>   * Capabilities can be set on Options classes
>   * WebElement rect method is now forward compatible for OSS endpoints (#6355)
>   * Deprecation warnings now have a stacklevel of 2
>   * keep_alive can now be set on Webdriver init (#6316)
>   * isDisplayed atom is now used for all w3c compliant browser, fixing issue with Safari 12
>
> Selenium 3.14.0
>   * Fix doc of URL-related ExpectedCondition (#6236)
>   * Added ExpectedCondition invisibility_of_element
>   * Swap out httplib for urllib3
>   * Be consistent with webdriver init kwarg service_log_path (#5725)
>
> Selenium 3.13.0
>
> - Add executing Chrome devtools command (#5989)
> - fix incorrect w3c action encoding in python client (#6014)
> - Implement context manager for WebDriver
> - Stop sending "windowHandle" param in maximize_window command for w3c
>
> Selenium 3.12.0
>
> - Add desired_capabilities keyword to IE and Firefox drivers for driver consitency
> - Fix bug with creating Safari webdriver instance (#5578)
> - Add support for Safari extension command
> - Deprecate Options `set_headless` methods in favor of property setter
> - Only set --disable-gpu for Chrome headless when on Windows
> - Add selenium User-Agent header (#5696)
> - Remote webdriver can now be started when passing options
> - All Options.to_capabilities now start with default DesiredCapabilities
> - Improve the error message that is raised when safaridriver cannot be found (#5739)
> - IeOptions class is now imported to selenium.webdriver
> - Remove the beta `authenticate` methods from `Alert`
>
> Selenium 3.11.0
>
> No changes just keeping python version in step with the rest of the
>   project.
>
> Selenium 3.10.0
>
> - make tests to check clicking on disabled element work for w3c compliant drivers (#5561)
> - add docstring for InvalidElementStateException. Fixes #5520
> - Deleting unused imports
> - Making python specification in IDEA project more generic
> - It should be possible to use a custom safaridriver executable to run Selenium's test suite.
>
> Selenium 3.9.0
>
> - Add docstrings to WebElement find methods (#5384)
> - Additional data in unexpected alert error is now handled for w3c drivers (#5416)
> - Allow service_args to be passed into Firefox WebDriver (#5421)
> - Fix bug introduced with response logging in 3.8.1 (#5362)
>
> Selenium 3.8.1
>
> - Fix bug when creating an Opera driver (#5266)
> - Stop sending sessionId in w3c payload. (#4620)
> - Fix issue with w3c actions releasing on element (#5180)
> - A more descriptive log message is displayed if the port cannot be connected (#2913)
> - Initialize Alert object by calling alert.text (#1863)
> - PhantomJS is now deprecated, please use either Chrome or Firefox in headless mode
> - Legacy Firefox driver: ensuring copy of profile dir, its 'extensions' subdir and 'user.js' file are writable. (#1466)
>
> Selenium 3.8.0
>
> - Firefox options can now be imported from selenium.webdriver as FirefoxOptions (#5120)
> - Headless mode can now be set in Chrome Options using `set_headless`
> - Headless mode can now be set in Firefox Options using `set_headless`
> - Add the WebKitGTK WebDriver and options class (#4635)
> - Browser options can now be passed to remote WebDriver via the `options` parameter
> - Browser option parameters are now standardized across drivers as `options`. `firefox_options`,   `chrome_options`, and `ie_options` are
>     now deprecated
> - Added missing W3C Error Codes (#4556)
> - Support has been removed for Python versions 2.6 and 3.3
>
> Selenium 3.7.0
>
> - need to pass applicable environment variables to tox
> - Fix active_element for w3c drivers (#3979)
> - add support for minimize command
> - add support for fullscreen command
> - window rect commands should fail on firefox and remote (legacy)
> - Fix python backward compatibility for window commands (#4937)
> - Update docstrings to specify the type of path needed to install firefox addons. (#4881)
> - Update python chromeOptions key for capabilities (#4622)
> - Fix python pause action implementation (#4795)
>
> Selenium 3.6.0
>
> - Fix package name in python webelement module (#4670)
> - Fix python driver examples (#3872)
> - No need to multiply pause by 1000
> - Add pause to action chains
> - only check for proxyType once
> - lowercase proxy type for w3c payload in python #4574
> - guarding against null return value from find_elements in python #4555
> - remove unnecessary pytest marking, address flake8 issues
> - allow IE WebDriver to accept IE Options
> - add IE Options class
> - convert OSS capabilities to W3C equivalent for W3C payload
> - Add Safari to API docs
>
> Selenium 3.5.0
>
> - Numerous test fixes
>     *Iterate over capabilities in a way to support py2.7 and py3
> - Fix W3C switching to window by name.
> - Support GeckoDriver addon install/uninstall commands  #4215.
> - Move firefox_profile into moz:firefoxOptions.
> - Filter non-W3C capability names out of alwaysMatch.
> - Honor cmd line args passed to Service ctor (#4167)
> - Add expected conditions based on URL to Python Expected Conditions #4160
> - Add network emulation to Chrome Python bindings (#4011)
> - add warning when saving incorrectly named screenshot (#4141)
>
> Selenium 3.4.3
>   * Fix EventFiringWebdriver and WebElement to raise AttributeError on missing attributes. (#4107)
>   * unwrap WebElements inside dicts
>
> Selenium 3.4.2
>
> - translate move_by_offset command to w3c
> - Update capabilities properly instead of assuming dict structure. Fixes #3927
> - Add missing file for Chrome options to API docs.
> - Add Chrome options module to API docs.
>
> Selenium 3.4.1
>   * Add back the ability to set profile when using Firefox 45ESR. Fixes #3897
>
> Selenium 3.4.0
>   * Correct usage of newSession around `firstMatch` and `alwaysMatch`
>   * Remove superfluous capabilities that are not needed
>   * Add expected condition that waits for all found elements to be visible (#3532)
>   * Allow methods wrapped by EventFiringWebDriver and EventFiringWebElement (#806)
>   * Dropping `javascriptEnabled` capability for real browsers
>   * Use W3C check from parent object instead of assuming from capabilities
>   * Bump example source distribution to match latest release.
>   * Replace TypeError with KeyError in remote webdriver error handler code (#3826)
>   * When testing Marionette use default capabilities in testing
>   * Conform to the api of urllib2 for adding header for a request (#3803)
>   * Add `text` key to alert#sendKeys parameters for W3C Endpoint
>   * Location once scrolled into view should use W3C executeScript endpoint not JSONWP
>   * Fixed the usage information in documentation of "save_screenshot". (#3804)
>   * Add Element Not Interactable exception
>   * Clean up imports in error handler
>   * flake8 cleanup
>
> Selenium 3.3.3
>
> - make w3c execute_script commands unique
>
> Selenium 3.3.2
>
> - Update window commands to use W3C End points
> - Update Alert when in W3C mode to use W3C Endpoints
> - Update to new W3C Execute Script end points
> - Add setting/getting proxy details to Firefox Options
> - Deprecate the use of browser profile when instantiating a session
> - Update start session to handle the W3C New Session
> - Add get/set window rect commands
> - Add InvalidArgumentException
> - When passing in `text` to send_keys, make sure we send a string not array
> - Fix string decoding in remote connection (#3663)
> - Fix indentation to satisfy PEP8
> - Try use old way of setting page load timeout if new way fails. Fixes #3654
> - fix file uploads for Firefox
> - Run unit tests on Python 3.3, 3.4, and 3.5 (#3638)
> - Fix indentation in double_click.
> - Fix non-W3C page load timeout setting.
>
> Selenium 3.3.1
>   * Fix encoding of basic auth header when using Python 3 Fixes #3622
>   * Add initial unit test suite
>   * Update W3C Timeout setting to be in line with the specification
>   * support.ui.Select class inherits from object (#3067)
>   * fix bug in proxy constructor that some properties are not proper set (#3459)
>   * Fix flake8 issues (#3628)
>
> Selenium 3.3.0
>   ** Note ** If you are updating to this version, please also update GeckoDriver to v0.15.0
>   * Fix python HTTPS encoding for python driver (#3379)
>   * Allow Firefox preferences to be set directly in Options
>   * Fix shutdown and process termination (#3263)
>   * Preventing exception if log_path is none or empty. Fixes #3128
>   * Add the W3C capability to Firefox for accepting insecure certificates
>   * Initial implementation of Pointer Actions
>   * Only skip tests if driver name matches a directory name.
>   * Update calls that return a pure object with keys to look for 'value' key
>   * Initial W3C Actions support
>   * fix docs output directory
>
> Selenium 3.0.2
>   * Add support for W3C Get Active Element
>   * Return when we use executeScript for faking WebElement.get_property
>   * Expand user paths and resolve absolute path for Chrome extensions
>   * Add support for verbose logging and custom path to EdgeDriver
>   * Update TakeElementScreenshot to match WebDriver specification
>   * Raise WebDriverException when FirefoxBinary fails to locate binary
>   * Fix getting IP for python 3
>   * Write Service log to DEVNULL by default
>   * Only attempt to remove the Firefox profile path if one was specified
>   * Added context manager for chrome/content in Firefox
>
> Selenium 3.0.1
>   * Fix regressions with python 3
>   * Add support for Safari Technology Preview
>
> Selenium 3.0.0
>   * new FirefoxDriver ctor precedence logic and moz:firefoxOptions support (#2882)
>   * Add W3C Set Window Position and W3C Get Window Position
>   * enable log path setting from firefox webdriver (#2700)
>   * Correct encoding of getAttribute.js and only load it once. Fixes #2785
>   * Encode the isDisplayed atom and only load it once
>
> Selenium 3.0.0.b3
>   * Use atoms for get_attribute and is_displayed when communicating with   a w3c compliant remote end.
>   * Make it possible to specialise web element
>
> Selenium 3.0.0.b2
>   * Updated Marionette port argument to match other drivers.
>
> Selenium 3.0.0.b1
>   * Fix basestring reference to work with python 3. Fixes #1820
>   * Correct Length conditional when filtering in PhantomJS. Fixes #1817
>   * Fix send keys when using PUA keys e.g. Keys.RIGHT #1839
>   * Fix cookie file leak in PhantomJS #1854
>   * Use the correct binary path when using Marionette
>   * Fixed: Unhelpful error message when PhantomJS exits. (#2173 #2168)
>   * Fix broken link to python documentation (#2159)
>   * Attempt to remove Firefox profile when using Marionette
>   * Ensure all capabilities are either within desiredCapabilities or requiredCapabilities
>   * Correct the expected capability name for the Firefox profile
>   * Add Firefox options to capabilities
>   * Visibility_of_all implies it only returns elements if all visible (#2052)
>   * Find visible elements (#2041)
>   *  Pass the firefox_profile as a desired capability in the Python client when using a remote server
>   * Avoid checking exception details for invalid locators due to differences in server implementations
>   * Handle capabilities better with Marionette and GeckoDriver
>   * Updated the maxVersion of FirefoxDriver xpi maxVersion to work with Firefox 47.0.1
>   * Remove Selenium RC support
>
> Selenium 2.53.0
>   * Adding Options object for use with Python FirefoxDriver
>   * Fixed improper usage of super in exceptions module
>   * create a temp file for cookies in phantomjs if not specified
>   * Pass in the executable that FirefoxBinary finds to the service if there isnt one passed in as a kwarg or capability
>   * Applied some DRY and extracted out the keys_to_typing()
>   * Fix deselecting options in
>
> Selenium 2.52.0
>   * Fixing case where UnexpectedAlertException doesn't get the alert_text in the error object
>   * Firefox: Actually use launch_browser timeout Fixes #1300
>
> Selenium 2.51.1
>   * correcting bundling issue missing README.rst file
>
> Selenium 2.51.0
>   * Firefox updates (see java changelog)
>
> Selenium 2.50.1
>   * Fixing error message handling. Fixes issue #1497
>   * Fixing error message handling. Fixes issue #1507
>   * Update webelement to handle W3C commands for size/location and rect
>   * rewrite click scrolling tests to match the Java ones
>
> Selenium 2.50.0
>   * handle potential URLError from sending shutdown, set self.process to None after it's already been quit
>   * Add support for submit() with W3C compliant endpoint
>
> Selenium 2.49.1
>   * Ensure you can close stream before attempting to close it.
>   * message response may cause json loads ValueError when it's not actually json   and just a string (like the message that occurs when
>   firefox driver thinks   another element will receive the click)
>   * Cleanup some error handling when sniffing what protocol you are speaking
>
> Selenium 2.49.0
>   * Have Firefox service write to a file instead of PIPE
>   * on osx for firefox, fallback to checking homebrew install, if the default isn't there
>   * Added Firefox path variable for string placeholder
>   * Update README to show Python 3.2+
>   * refactoring all the service classes to use a common one.
>   * Add Firefox specific command to switch context between Browser content and Browser chrome
>   * updating files after go copyright:update
>   * Use specificationLevel to know that we are speaking GeckoDriver
>   * Bug fixes: #1294, #1186
>
> Selenium 2.48.0
>   * Update error pulling to match spec when we encounter a spec compliant browser.
>   * Disable tests that are not working with Marionette when running Marionette tests
>   * Add the ability to run python marionette tests
>   * Python 3 compatibility for remote Authorization
>   * changing casing of children finding tests
>
> Selenium 2.47.3
>   * Bring back py 3 support
>
> Selenium 2.47.2
>   * Fix running Edge driver locally on win10
>   * adding repr to WebDriver and WebElement
>
> Selenium 2.47.1
>   * Fix the issue of deleting the profile when shutting down Firefox
>   * WebElement **eq** compares against more types
>   * Issues fixed: 850
>
> Selenium 2.47.0
>   * Add in support for when communicating with a Spec compliant browsers
>   * Initial support for Edge using EdgeDriver
>   * Issues fixed: 818
>
> Selenium 2.46.1
>   * Adding ability to make remote call for webelement screenshots in accordance to the W3C spec
>   * Adding api to authenticate HTTP Auth modal dialogs via driver.switch_to.alert (beta)
>   * Add rebeccapurple to Color Object
>   * Add element screenshot
>   * Add service handler and minimal update to driver to use service for Marionette
>   * Add the ability to start FirefoxDriver backed with Marionette via a capability
>   * support socket timeout for connections
>   * free_port checks if port is available on all interfaces
>   * Allow error handling to handle both current errors and w3c errors
>   * Update find_elements to match spec
>   * phantomjs: service: remove unused import of signal
>   * phantomjs: add port information to WebDriverException
>   * Issues fixed (Github): 478, 612, 734, 780
>
> Selenium 2.46.0
>   * Firefox support up to 38
>   * BlackBerry browser support
>   * remove Presto-Opera support
>   * firefox extension extraction fixes
>   * process management fixes with phantomjs
>   * Comparing remote web element for equality does not require a remote command
>   * Issues Fixed: (gcode) 8493, 8521, 8498, 8274, 8497, 5923
>   * Issues Fixed: (github) 401
>
> Selenium 2.45.0
>   * Firefox support up to 35, support for native events up to 34.
>   * Make Opera driver support also the new Blink based Opera
>   * README: Fix the Yahoo example
>   * WebElement docstring fixes
>   * Add debugger_address option to the ChromeDriver options list to optionally instruct ChromeDriver to wait for the target devtools
>   instance to be started at a given host:ip
>   * Set default value for PhantomJS process reference
>   * Allow setting of FileDetector for send_keys
>   * Pass info to TimeoutException in WebDriverWait
>   * Issues Fixed: 8065, 8310, 8539
>
> Selenium 2.44.0
>   * (previous release person forgot to add release notes! DAVID!)
>
> Selenium 2.43.0
>   * Expand WebElement.get_attribute API docs
>   * firefox may be installed without admininstrator privileges
>       and therefore there may be no HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE entry. Issue #7784
>   * UnexpectedAlertPresentException should contain the alert text in python too. Issue #7745
>   * don't mutate the global 'ignored exceptions', take a copy of the globally specified ones, change the   global to be a tuple instead.
>   Issue #7725
>   * raise exception when the firefox binary isn't actually found, which usually implies the upgrade failed (on windows) Issue #6092 ,#6847
>   * Fixing NameError: global name 'options' is not defined.
>   * Remove unused import subprocess.PIPE
>   * Redirect Firefox output to /dev/null by default Fixes Issue #7677
>   * More flexible management of http timeouts in Selenium RC python client
>   * Generate Python API docs for selenium.webdriver.chrome.options. Fixes issue #7471
>   * Use 127.0.0.1 as localhost name resolving might fail on some systems
>
> Selenium 2.42.1
>   * Fixed Py3 issues
>   * Make firefox_binary.py and firefox_profile.py not executable
>   * Make exceptions Python 3 compatible
>
> Selenium 2.42
>   * Support for Firefox 29 Native Events
>   * "remote_url" and "remote_browser" parameters for "./go test_remote".
>   * missing **init** in new android module
>   * issue #7304 Fix memory leak caused by **del** in PhantomJS
>   * File upload using remotedriver on python3
>   * Updating xpi install to align with mozprofile
>   * command_executor should also support unicode strings as well.
>
> Selenium 2.41
>   * Support for Firefox 28
>   * deprecating switch_to_* in favour of driver.switch_to.*
>
> Selenium 2.40
>   * Support for Firefox 27
>   * Fixes related to http connection
>   * Fix for phantomjs running on windows #6736
>
> Selenium 2.39
>   * Support for Firefox 26
>
> Selenium 2.38.4
>   * keep-alive can't be used for phantomjs / IE, fix for that and tested for py3 :)
>
> Selenium 2.38.3
>   * really supporting py3 :)
>
> Selenium 2.38.2
>   * py3 support (once again)
>
> Selenium 2.38.1
>   * fix packaging problem where firefox/webdriver_prefs.json was missing
>
> Selenium 2.38
>   * Support for Firefox 25
>   * FirefoxProfile now using common webdriver.json instead of having our own copy in py
>     - behavior change to the preferences is that they now should be treated
>       like raw types rather than strings and allow the json library to translate
>       the types appropriated (e.g. True => true)
>
> - Set proper 'Accept' request header so that Python bindings work with some old WebDriver implementations that reply 404 to requests with no
>     'Accept' set.
> - handle redirect response explicitly (since switching to using keep-alive)
> - phantomjs service needs to really kill the spawned process Issue #5921
> - removing old api endpoints from command listing
> - using keep-alive for remote connection
> - adjusting phantomjs subprocess.Popen
> - ActionsChains.send_keys should use /keys endpoint Issue #6348
> - fix TypeError in chrome_options.extensions for Python3.x
> - Other Bugs Fixed: #6531, #6513, #4569, #6454
>
> Selenium 2.37.2
>   * fix regression added with unicode fix
>   * Bug fix #6360
>
> Selenium 2.37.1
>   * fix find_elements on webelement using unicode locators and py 2.7
>
> Selenium 2.37
>   * repackage with fix for Firefox native events on Linux
>   * fix issue with unicode By locators w/ python 2.7 #6430
>
> Selenium 2.36
>   * Added Safari WebDriver. Fixes issue 5352.
>   * fix platform for safari caps
>   * Convert all offsets/coordinates/speeds into integers
>   * Fix drag and drop by offset behaviour
>   * Fix initialization of Proxy by capabilities when proxyType is set
>   * Enable SOCKS proxy support
>   * Validation of passed locator for find_element(s) methods #5690
>   * Adding support for /status, /sessions commands
>   * Doc fixes
>   * ability to set Chrome extensions by using base64 encoded strings #4013
>   * fix logic regarding Select.select_by_visible_text #3910
>   * Bugs fixed: #6165, #6231
>
> Selenium 2.35
>   * Remove duplicate 'get screenshot as file' methods.  Add method 'get_screenshot_as_png'
>   * fixing UnicodeEncodeError on get attribute of webelement
>
> Selenium 2.34
>   * Corrected webdriverbackedselenium session handling. Fixes issue 4283
>   * Corrected use of basestring for python 3. Fixes issue 5924
>   * Support for Firefox 22
>   * Added support for logging from the browser
>   * corrected proxy handling on FirefoxProfile
>   * Corrected handling of chrome extensions. Fixes issue 5762
>
> Selenium 2.33
>   * getText() ignores elements in the 
>   * Adding both official and informal string representations to Color object.
>   * Replace distutils.dir_util by shutil
>   * Allow finding firefox binary at ProgramFiles(x86) on windows(64 bit)
>   * Py3 compatible winreg import and content-type access
>
> Selenium 2.32
>   * Support for FF20 Native Events
>   * Python 3 support
>   * Misc Python 3 patches
>   * Allow easy FirefoxBinary subclassing
>
> Selenium 2.31
>   * Support for FF19 native events
>   * web element equality is now in conformance with other language bindings
>
> Selenium 2.30
>   * Allow env to be specified for the chromedriver service
>   * Allow log path to be specified for phantomjs driver service.
>   * Bug Fixes: 4608 4940 4974 5034 5075
>
> Selenium 2.29
>   * Allow subclassing of driver and have the ability to send_keys Issue 4877, 5017
>   * Simplifying save_screenshot and allow phantomjs to take screenshots
>
> Selenium 2.28
>   * "null" can now be passed to executeScript
>   * Add transparent and extended colour keywords to color support module. Fixes issue 4866
>
> Selenium 2.27
>   * Added support for phantomjs / ghostdriver
>   * Fix python client, avoid duplicate chrome option items after reusing options class. Fixes Issue 4744.
>   * adding colour support to Python. fixes issue 4623
>   * Adding log_path/service_log_path as named kwargs for chrome
>
> Selenium 2.26
>   * Added location_when_scrolled_into_view - Bug 4357
>   * Added new expected_conditions support module to be used with WebDriverWait
>
> Selenium 2.25
>   * Jython 2.7 Support - Bug 3988
>   * EventFiringWebDriver added to Support module - Bug 2267
>   * Added IEDriverServer logging that can be accessed via desired capabilities
>   * Fixed by data being passed into find_elements - bug 3735
>   * Removed deprecated ChromeDriver items around desiredcapabilites in favour of chrome options
>   * Added default values for a number of action_chains calls
>
> Selenium 2.24
>   * Removing the ctypes approach of invoking IEDriver, you will need to download the IEDriverServer from
>   https://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list
>
> Selenium 2.23
>   * Support for FF13 native events
>
> Selenium 2.22
>   * Moving IEDriver to be able to use IEDriverServer
>
> Selenium 2.21.3
>   * Fix for File Upload to remote servers
>   * Better handling of typing in input=file. Bug 3831, 3736
>   * Better handling of unicode URLS Bug 3740
>
> Selenium 2.21.2
>   * Fix typing to file input when not using Selenium Server. Bug 3736
>
> Selenium 2.21.1
>   * focusmanager.testmode messes with native events, removing it.
>
> Selenium 2.21
>   * Local File upload capabilities for non-remote browser
>   * Adding maximize_window api call
>   * Updating default firefox profile to set focusmanager.testmode to true
>       see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=704583
>   * bugs fixed: 3506, 3528, 3607
>
> Selenium 2.20
>   * disable native events for FF on Mac by default
>   * fix webdriverwait to execute at least once when using 0 timeout
>   * Fixed Issue 3438
>
> Selenium 2.19
>   * WebDriverBackedSelenium is now avalaible to all languages
>   * Addon installation fixes
>
> Selenium 2.18
>   * Proxy capabilities passing
>
> Selenium 2.17
>   * OperaDriver can now be invoked by webdriver.Opera()
>   * Support has been added for ChomeOptions. This deprecates support passing in DesiredCapabilities
>   * Proxy class to tell the browser a proxy is in use. Currently only for Firefox
>
> Selenium 2.16
>   * bug fixes
>
> Selenium 2.15
>   * bug fixes
>
> Selenium 2.14
>   * Fix for LD_PRELOAD being polluted by WebDriver
>   * Added Orientation API
>   * A fix for Error Handling

Comment: so I must migrate to seleniumLibrary to Selenium4Library ?

Comment: What should I change to be able to do that, and do you have any example of website testing using selenium4 ?